# php mass variables from sql query

Tags: php, sql, variables

I have this section of my PHP script that loops through a recordset and stores the data into variables.

```
 $sql_result5 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM turfs WHERE city = '$city'", $db); $query++;
 while ($rs5 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result5)) { 
    if ($rs5[plot] != "") {
       ${$rs5[plot].'_exist'} = 1; 
       ${'$p_color_'.$rs5[plot]} = $rs5[color]; 
       ${$rs5[plot].'_1'} = $rs5[color1]; 
       }
    }
```

I then use this data to populate a 20x20 grid, so that loop would be going through 400 records storing data for each, and for each record (box in the grid) there needs to be about 5 or so variables.

Is it a bad idea creating so many variables? Is there a better way to do this? Maybe an array?

Comment: Don't create individual variables for each, build an array... if you want a 20x20 grid, build a 2-d array

Comment: I'm not too familiar with arrays, but this would be ok if I had 5 or so different variables for each square in a 20x20 grid?

Comment: @user1022585 Naming variables only-the-fly (as you do it) is never a good idea. It's bound to cause trouble. You should read up on how arrays works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating variables, as you've done, isn't the best way to do this. Instead, either use an `array`, or create the grid within the `while` loop.

## Create an Array

```
$sql_result5 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM turfs WHERE city = '$city'", $db);
$query++;
while($rs5 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result5)){
 if($rs5[plot]){
  $plot[$rs5[plot]] = array(
   'color' => $rs5[color],
   'color1' => $rs5[color1],
  );
 }
}
```

**Then...**

```
foreach($plot as $this_plot){
 $color = $this_plot['color'];
 $color1 = $this_plot['color1'];
 // Do something here
}
```

## Or, Create Grid Within `while`

```
$sql_result5 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM turfs WHERE city = '$city'", $db);
$query++;
while($rs5 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result5)){ 
 if($rs5[plot]){
  $color = $rs5['color'];
  $color1 = $rs5['color1'];
  // Do something here
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql_result5 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM turfs WHERE city = '$city'", $db); $query++;
$plots = array();
$i = 0;
while ($rs5 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result5)) {  
    $plots[$i] = $rs5;    
    $i++;
} 

//Then when you're rendering...
$i=0;
foreach($plots as $space)
{
    $space['color'];
}
```

Just depends on how you want to publish the information. You can create a 2D array but for your purposes I don't think its necessary. You just have to create a new row every 20 items.